# React shows a blank screen instead of a rendered "Failed to compile" backtrace

Tags: reactjs, error-handling

I'm using functional components and I'm in development mode.

Whenever there is an error, it shows the error in the browser console normally. However, the UI only shows a white screen. I'd like to show errors just like in the image below:

[image: React Failed to compile backtrace]

Does anyone know a solution to this problem? The idea is not to fix the error, but just to render the error in the UI.

I already tried to remove StrictMode and installed redbox-react. I did research on the topic and couldn't find the solution specific to this problem. I'm having this problem with other apps, so I don't think reinstalling will solve the problem.

I created this error on purpose in order to test (the onClick is empty):

EDIT:

```
<a href="#create"onClick={() => {}} className="add-contact">
    Add contact
</a>
```

Also it would be the same if this array below were empty:

```
emptyArray.map(arr => <div>{arr}</div>)
```

Comment: Why dont you think to add more code to see what do you have? Are you checking the developer console to see the error??

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I added more code in question. Yes, the error in the console is showing normally as we expect.

Comment: Your app should broken in browser too,  if you write wrong code. I think you need to restart your terminal and refresh your browser and also restart your IDE. Then your browser will be broken if you have buggy code